# How does variable assignment works in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Ruby version: ruby 2.6.7p197 (2021-04-05 revision 67941) [x86_64-linux]

### Rails gem version: 6.0.1

---

Simple question, I have this example **on rails console**

As expected, if I try to call a non existent variable, I got an error

```rb
irb(main):007:0> value
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#         2: from (irb):7
#        1: from (irb):7:in `rescue in irb_binding'
# NameError (undefined local variable or method `value' for main:Object)
```

But if I try to do the following example

```rb
(value = 1) if value.present?
```

It returns nil for some reason, the first scenario this happenned there was no parenthesis, I thought it was defining the variable and then returning a value of nil, but then I tried with it and just happened again (I tried other variable because ruby counted that as a defined variable)

#### OBS: I tried the same scenario on raw irb and it raised me an error, <s>this only happens on rails console</s>

#### EDIT: It only raised an error because I didn't realized that '.present?' is a rails method, but if I change my syntax to

```rb
(value = 1) if value
```

#### the same behaviour happens

---

Why does that happen? Shouldn't a NameError be raised?

Comment: "I tried the same scenario on raw irb and it raised me an error, this only happens on rails console" that error did not happen to be a `NoMethodError` did it?  Because `value = 1 if value.nil?` works just fine. The parser recognizes the first `value` and initializes as `nil` then processes the right hand side. e.g. `b = 7 if 1 == 2; b #=> nil`

Comment: @engineersmnky, Yes, I fixed the post example, but the same behaviour still happens if I pass the variable itself, the point is; why there is no NameError exception being raised?

Comment: @engineersmnky I forgot to mention, "why there is no NameError exception being raised? WITH the parenthesis"

Comment: I think I already explained this the parse reads top to bottom, left to right, so when it sees `value` assignment, it treats it as a local variable even though the assignment has not occurred yet. Then the interpreter sweeps through and it evaluates the modifier `if` first (as it should) and since `value` has already been determined to be a local variable (albeit without a value) there is no `NameError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby works such way, please look [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods)

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs:
>
> ```
> a = 0 if false # does not assign to a
>
> p local_variables # prints [:a]
>
> p a # prints nil
> ```

And other interesting thing:

> Another commonly confusing case is when using a modifier if:
>
> ```
> p a if a = 0.zero?
> ```
>
> Rather than printing “true” you receive a `NameError, “undefined local variable or method 'a'”`. Since ruby parses the bare a left of the if first and has not yet seen an assignment to a it assumes you wish to call a method. Ruby then sees the assignment to a and will assume you are referencing a local method.
>
> The confusion comes from the out-of-order execution of the expression. First the local variable is assigned-to then you attempt to call a nonexistent method.

So you can

Comment: They might also benefit from reviewing the official getting started docs for [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) and the [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)